# How can I fix the screen going black after the "hello games" title showing up?

Tags: pc, no-mans-sky

I launched the game and it displayed the Hello Games intro and then the screen goes black. No patch seems to fix this. How can I fix this issue?

Technical specifications: 8 GB RAM, 2.10 GHz AMD A6-3500 APU with Raedon HD graphics and 64 bit windows 10.

Comment: this setup doesn't conform with the system requirements, which indicate that you need at least an GTX 480 (or Radeon 7870) to play. with the integrated gpu you would probably get 3-5 fps ... :/

Answer (score 3):

There's your problem, the AMD APU.

No Mans Sky used a set of commands only available on Intel PCs and more recent AMD processors, the SSE 4.1 command set. This makes it so certain older AMD processors can't play.

If you got the steam version, there is an experimental branch(code = "3xperimental"),  it might solve your problem.

Comment: No. Many amd cpu/apus support sse4.1

Comment: @ardaozkal however, that specific error has come up many times on the subreddit for No Mans Sky and that's the reason it happens

Comment: Some (and most of the Recent) amd cpu/apus can play the game.

Comment: The "only available on Intel PCs" part of your answer isn't accurate.

Comment: Sorry, I'll fix that

Answer (score 0):

i managed to get it working. Very simple, just click the nms.exe and leave the cursor on it, then hit 'return' to launch, then quicly hit a second time to launch a second time...

if done correctly, the game will load in two windows, one dummy, not working, the other 100% working..

hope it works in your case too. see ya

Comment: This has got to be the most bizzare workaround I've ever geard of.